# Passing variable length argument to function C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function that accepts variable number of arguments. But I am getting error in expression `decltype(std::initializer_list::size_type) res1=0;` as `error: expected primary-expression before 'decltype'`.  The purpose is to declare appropriate variable type that can hold sum of the list (although this declaration will create big enough variable to hold all elements of the list only and not their sum). How can I do this?

Also, how can I make appropriate function return type to return  `res1` instead of `void`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

void sum1(std::initializer_list<int> lst1)
{
    decltype(std::initializer_list::size_type) res1=0;
    for(auto v1:lst1)
    {
        res1 += v1;
    }
    std::cout<<" sum = \n"<<res1;
}
int main()
{
    sum1({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});
    //auto b = sum1({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `decltype(lst1)::value_type`. But if you know your function always accepts `initializer_list<int>`, then you should declare the result type as `long long res1 = 0;`, or you could check if your compiler supports a 128 bit integer and use that type instead.

Comment: Consider using [`std::accumulate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) instead of `for()`, then you can use `auto` to declare `res1`, eg: `auto res1 = std::accumulate(lst1.begin(), lst1.end(), 0);`

Answer (score 1):

`size_type` is not needed for anything in your function. The `initializer_list` has type `int`, therefore `res1` should be an `int` and your return type should be `int`. If you really want to derive the value type from the initializer_list then do so like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

auto sum1(std::initializer_list<int> lst1)
{
    typename std::initializer_list<int>::value_type res1 = 0;
    for(auto v1:lst1)
    {
        res1 += v1;
    }

    return res1;
}

int main()
{
    sum1({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});
    auto b = sum1({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you want the function to be generic, in which case it is necessary to derive the value type, then the template function looks like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template<typename T>
auto sum1(std::initializer_list<T> lst1)
{
    typename std::initializer_list<T>::value_type res1 = 0;
    for(auto v1:lst1)
    {
        res1 += v1;
    }

    return res1;
}

int main()
{
    sum1({1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6,7.7,8.8,9.9,10.10});
    auto b = sum1({1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6,7.7,8.8,9.9,10.10});
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that Return Type Deduction requires C++14 or later. For C++11, you have to explicitly specify a trailing return type when using `auto`, eg: `auto sum1(std::initializer_list<int> lst1) -> int` or `auto sum1(std::initializer_list<T> lst1) -> T`

Answer (score 0):

Following is corrected code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

int sum1(std::initializer_list<int> lst1)
{
    int res1=0;
    for(auto v1:lst1)
    {
        res1 += v1;
    }
    return res1;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout<<" sum = "<<sum1({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});
    //auto b = sum1({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});
    return 0;
}
```

You can see working [here](https://ideone.com/oJs2QU).

**Note:** You can change the type of `res0` to `long` or other type if result is not in the limits of `int`. Also, Change the return type of function `sum1` accordingly.